# Keras model import name is not defined

Tags: python, keras

I'm not sure why the model isn't defined

Taken from here
https://github.com/DariusAf/MesoNet/blob/master/example.py

## Code:

```
from classifiers import *
from pipeline import *
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
classifier = Meso4()
classifier.load('Meso4_DF')
```

## gives error:

```
classifier = Meso4()
NameError: name 'Meso4' is not defined
```

Comment: How did you get `example.py` from that repo on your local environment? Did you clone the entire repo?

Comment: Copy-paste, I'm not that great with GitHub. I've got the Meso4_DF weights file, but is Meso4() referencing another one?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `Meso4` is defined in `classifiers.py`, [as you can see here](https://github.com/DariusAf/MesoNet/blob/master/classifiers.py).

Strictly speaking, your problem would be solved by also downloading the `classifiers.py` file and putting it in the same directory as your `example.py` file.

*However*, you should, in general, refrain from copy-pasting code from GitHub unless you know what you are doing, and if you need to wonder if you do, you don't.

Therefore, I recommend actually [cloning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) the [repo](https://github.com/DariusAf/MesoNet) and working from the local copy.